# In Perl, how can I remove a + sign from a string using regex substitution?

Tags: perl

In Perl I have a URL reading as `health+development` and I want to remove the `+` from the middle so that it can read as `health development`. any ideas will save my time.

Comment: Did you try *anything* before asking SO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a look at [search and replace using regular expressions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html#Search-and-replace).

But to save you time, here is a quick demonstration:

```
my $str = 'health+development';
$str =~ s/\+/ /; # replace '+' with ' '
print $str;
```

Comment: thanks...i am just learning perl now.

Answer (score 6):

You really should use [URI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?URI) to parse the url. `+` is not the only special character in urls. I'd provide some code, but you didn't specify which part of the url that is.

Answer (score 2):

You should follow [@ikegami's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11237485/100754) for parsing URLs.

As for removing `+` signs from strings, I find character classes more readable than slash-escapes:

```
my $s = 'health+development+topics';
$s =~ s/ [+] / /gx;
print "$s\n";
```

Comment: Transliteration is even more readable. `tr/+/ /`

Comment: And transliteration is faster then a regexp substitution.